# differentiate web favicon for iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, favicon, retina-display

Is there a way to say to use 1 icon for an iPad and another for an iPhone? The only fav icon code I know of is `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.jpg">` but that is just generic Apple and doesn't specify device. And I presume since newer iPhones and iPads have the retina display, I would need a diff webapp icon for those, too, right??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure thing, from the excellent [Icon Handbook](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/examples/favicons/):

```
<!-- For iPhone 4 Retina display: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">

<!-- For iPad: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">

<!-- For iPhone: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
```

Comment: There's also a 144x144 for the retina iPads -- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons